# mod_authz_ldap subtree query configuration failing, searching root of LDAP tree instead

Tags: authentication, configuration, ldap, apache

I am trying to query a strange LDAP structure, which I need to authenticate against. Our app uses the REMOTE_USER variable to determine the user. I do not have access to the LDAP directory hence can't see it's logs.

The structure needs me query a sub part of the tree, demonstrated by this Perl script written to test the LDAP query (which works and returns a list of Users as expected)

```
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAP::Entry;

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new( 'ldapdevel.my.edu.au' ) or die "$@";
$mesg = $ldap->bind( 'uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au', password => 'bindpass' );


if( $mesg->code ) {
               die $mesg->error;
 }

$mesg = $ldap->search( # perform a search
        base   => "o=my.edu.au",
        filter => "cn=devraj"
      );


$mesg->code && die $mesg->error;

foreach $entry ($mesg->entries) { 
             $entry->dump;
}
```

My Apache configuration has the following in the VirtualHost entry, which aims to mimic the same query as described in the Perl script.

```
<Location />

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My Application"

    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPBindPassword bindpass

    AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au"
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://ldapdevel.my.edu.au/o=my.edu.au?cn?one"

    Require valid-user

</Location>
```

I can also confirm that Apache does successfully bind to the LDAP directory.

Apache error log, messages for LDAP authentication, which indicates that the URI is / hence Apache is searching the top of the directory and not the subtree of o=my.edu.au

```
[Tue Sep 04 16:22:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 04 16:22:20 2012] [info] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [26064] auth_ldap authenticate: user devraj authentication failed; URI / [User not found][No such object]
[Tue Sep 04 16:22:20 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] user devraj not found:
```

I realise that the issue is the AuthLDAPUrl, my question is what am I doing wrong in my AuthLDAPUrl , or should I be using another directive?

I've also tried to configure each parameter to mod_authz_ldap individually as follows:

```
<Location />

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My LDAP authenticated app"

    AuthzLDAPLogLevel debug

    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthBasicAuthoritative off
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

    AuthzLDAPBindPassword bindpass
    AuthzLDAPBindDN "uid=binduser,o=my.edu.au"

    AuthzLDAPMethod ldap
    AuthzLDAPServer ldapdevel.my.edu.au
    AuthzLDAPUserBase o=my.edu.au
    AuthzLDAPUserKey cn
    AuthzLDAPUserScope base
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute cn

    Require valid-user

</Location>
```

this actually works! BUT... Apache tried to bind as the user that's trying to log in, which obviously fails. If I login with the bind user credentials it passes the auth, Error log extract:

```
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [15628] bind as cn=devraj,l=X,ou=Students,o=my.edu.au failed: 49
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [15628] basic LDAP authentication of user 'devraj' failed
[Fri Sep 07 14:14:27 2012] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'devraj' not configured
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried changing your URL to look for the uid instead of the cn? I notice your bind user goes by the uid...

Comment: You might also change "one" to "sub", as I'm guessing your users are in a container within that ou.

Comment: @dearlbry we have a strange setup, bind is with uid, but user objects are queryed by cn. Will try sub. Thanks.

Comment: Changing one to sub makes no difference. Do you know if mod_ldap can log the LDAP queries?

Comment: If you bump up the Apache log level (like to Debug), does it not give any more data? Your setup doesn't sound that strange actually. And in order to authenticate users, they have to bind w/ the provided creds (rather than perform a lookup), so you should at least *try* using the uid: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.0.x/modules/experimental/mod_auth_ldap.c (search for mod_auth_ldap_check_user_id)

Comment: @dearlby thanks for that, have updated the question with a few more experiences. Any further thoughts would be appreciated.